# How to use WordPress Customizer API to insert image into pre-defined spots on homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Although I have developed custom WP themes before, this is the first time I have ever had to develop one that enables the client to customize some elements via the WP Customizer.

I already know how to enable the ability to upload a logo but I need another ability that I am just not sure how to implement.

The design of the site calls for an image grid - 2 rows of 3 images each, all the same height and width. The client is extremely non tech-savvy and rather than hard code it in the editor and hope that they can update it without messing up the code, I thought it would be easier to have 6 upload slots in the Customizer panel, one for each image. That way it is easy for the client to update and it won't risk breaking the code.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it. Can someone point me to a tutorial or code example that does this? Even if the example is for a single image, I can extrapolate it for my needs, I think.

Thanks in advance!

Best,

Cynthia

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Advanced Custom Fields. It's invaluable when adding custom fields to the editor and it's extremely quick and easy to deploy.

**Implementation**

Once implemented the following instructions should help:

1. Select **'Advanced Custom Fields'** from the admin navigation
2. Select **'Add New'**
3. Name the rule group
4. Select **'Add Field'**
5. Give the new field a **'Field Label'** such as **'Image One'**
6. In **'Field Type'** select **'Image'**
7. In **'Return Value'** select **'Image URL'**
8. In **rules** select 'Page' 'is equals to' {{Required Page}}
9. In **'Style'** select **'Standard (WP Meta Box)'**
10. Repeat Steps **4-9** to add the further image boxes
11. Select **'Publish'**
12. Edit the page specified in step **8**
13. Upload the images in to the new upload fields
14. Implement the below **PHP Snippet** to show the images in page

**PHP Snippet**

If you name the above created image fields 'image-1', 'image-2', 'image-3' etc. You can use the following loop to bring in the new fields on the front-end.

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();
for ($x = 0; $x <= 6; $x++) {
    echo '<img src="'.get_field('image-'.$x).'" alt="">';
} 
endwhile; else: endif; ?>
```

I've not tested the above code, so hopefully it's correct =P

**References**

[Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) - Wordpress plugin for adding custom CMS attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to use the Customizer for that, because it's not planned for such use, and all the css and information in the customizer is loaded in the header of all pages.

The way I do it for my customers is to set up a specific custom post type, with the potentially custom fields in a metabox (usually,text for a link, the url where the link should send, maybe a order to display on the home page), and use the normal thumbnail for the image, the normal title and the normal "content" for the text.

No need of advanced plugin :)